# Сборка проекта в .exe файл

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Всем доброго дня. Спасите, помогите. Не разберусь как правильно собрать проект. 45 строк кода, а весят 130 MB при сборке в .exe файл. Прочитал, что можно исключить из сборки некоторые файлы и библиотеки. Подскажите пожалуйста что еще можно сделать, куда смотреть и что жать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Режим развертывания поменяйте

Comment: [Модели развертывания](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/deploying/). В документации всё подробно описано. Но да, чтиво длинное.